# A way to configure Entity Framework Core to use brackets instead of quotes for identifiers?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using EF Core 7 and the Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore provider.

Apparently, identifiers in all the queries are quoted using double quotes (e.g. `"Schema"."Table"`), which on Oracle means that they are case-sensitive. For this specific project I'm working on, I'd prefer to use brackets (e.g. `[Schema].[Table]`), which are case-insensitive.

Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle RDBMS does not support the bracket syntax so generating brackets would result in invalid queries when they are parsed by the database.

You either use quoted identifiers `"schema"."table"`, which are case-senstive, or unquoted identifiers `schema.table`, which are effectively case-insensitive as the SQL engine will implicitly convert them to upper-case (so it is the same as using `"SCHEMA"."TABLE"`).

For more information on identifiers and naming rules you can look at the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) documentation.